# formly validation message with angularjs 1.2

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I am trying to add validation message for required input field with angularjs 1.2. All examples I have found so far refer to angular > 1.2 and use ng-messages.
I tried getting formControl and check form object but it is empty. This is my attempt:

```
        formlyConfig.setWrapper({
          name: 'validation',
          types: ['input'],
          templateUrl: 'my-messages.html'
        });
        formlyValidationMessages.addStringMessage('required', 'This field is required');
```

and in custom validation template:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-messages.html">
      <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
            {{ options }}
    </script>
```

The output is like:

{"templateOptions":{"required":true,"label":"Surname"},"type":"input","modelOptions":{"updateOn":"blur"},"key":"surname","extras":{},"data":{},"validation":{"messages":{},"errorExistsAndShouldBeVisible":false},"id":"sectionForm_input_surname_0","name":"sectionForm_input_surname_0","initialValue":"ffdsffdsfdsgds","formControl":{}}

so, formControl is empty object. errorExistsAndShouldBeVisible has appropriate value, it is set to true if field is empty, but messages are always empty object.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question, but why are using an old version of angular that has numerous issues that have been fixed since?  My advice would be to upgrade your version of angular.